# .NET framework 4 as prerequisite in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

How can I include .NET Framework 4 as a prerequisite in Prerequisite Dialog Box in VS 2008.

My purpose is in Launch Condition of setup and deployment project, .NET Framework 4 should be present and get installed with installer. (I would not prefer that installer downloads it from internet, rather from same place as my application start up).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support .NET 4.

If you want to develop using .NET 4 you will need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: The real problem is, my client's PC runs Windows 7 with .netframework 4 client profile. I am unable to install my application developed in VS2008. I tried uninstalling .NET Framework 4 From his PC and running the Clean up tool provided by Microsoft. But still I am unable to install it successfully

Comment: @Niraj - it might be worth editing that information into the question or perhaps starting a new question. This is important and will probably affect the number and quality of answers you get.